# EF Core 1.1 - How to check DbContext if migrations have been applied?

Tags: entity-framework-core

In EntityFramework Core 1.1 this method does not seem to exist anymore:

```
DbContext.AllMigrationsApplied()
```

What is the preferred way of doing this now. Is it?

```
if (!context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think `AllMigrationsApplied` ever existed in Entity Framework...

Yes, `!context.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any()` is the best way to do this in EFCore 1.1.0+.